# Where can someone find a public dataset on where/which USPS postal boxes and sorting machines have been removed?

Tags: usa, government, elections

The USPS is removing sorting machines and mail collection boxes from several locations. I've seen this mapped but cannot yet find this data.
[image]

https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/us/internal-usps-documents-raise-questions-about-effectiveness-of-sorting-machines-removal-order/ar-BB181ZRG